# Why <C-W> does not enter operator pending mode?

Tags: key-bindings, vim-windows

I use Colemak layout. In order to use hjkl I remapped several keys nearby with `noremap`. It works fine. However, window movement commands somehow do not recognize these mappings. E.g. although I have 'noremap n j' in my vimrc when I press `<C-W> n` it opens a new split instead of moving downwards.

It seems that `<C-W>` enters not operator pending mode but some other unknown state. Why is it the case? How can I do my mapping?

I don't want to map it like `noremap <C-w>n <C-w>j` because of the very small timeout (I need it for other commands).

Answer (score 4):

`CTRL-W` starts a window command, that means, Vim enters a [special mode](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/normal.c#L726-L731), which won't timeout, awaiting another command and which does not **allow** maps.
And this makes sense, since Ctrl-W is no command, after which a motion follows, so I wouldn't expect Operator Pending mode after Ctrl-W.

Comment: Oh. Well, this is reasonable, but having mappings for this mode also would be nice. Maybe I can squeeze something from langmap and exec mappings on Ctrl-W.

Comment: "And this makes sense" but it makes no sense. :)

Comment: @trusktr what `does not make sense`?

Comment: To an end user who hasn't delved into the details, pressing ctrl+w and seeing the character waiting for you looks exactly like operator pending mode. Even after reading your answer, I can't understand what it means (apart from perhaps it explaining simply what the code does, but I don't understand any _reason_ the code should actually do that and why it can't just be operator pending).

Comment: @trusktr The simple answer is, since `CTRL-W` starts a window management comment, it cannot logically act on any cursor movement that follows it. It simply does not make sense, or what should happen if you press `Ctrl-W` followed by `move to next word`? It simply does not work as an operation that acts over whatever motion follows.

Comment: That makes little sense to someone who doesn't care about Vim's implementation details. If you ask the question "what should happen if you press `Ctrl-W` followed by `the next pressed key`", then the answer is simple: whatever is mapped to it, and while we wait for that key it should be in operator pending just like with any other key. You detailed a Vim quirk by asking a question. Vim doesn't have to be implemented that way. It would be intuitive if `ctrl+w` entered operator pending mode. Why should it be special? Merely because of an implementation quirk.

Comment: Why should window command mode not time out, while operator pending mode can? Again, it's because of an inconsistent design of implementation. There's no intuitive answer to it, there is only "just because, that's how (the quirk) is coded". It's just not intuitive. Both Atom and VS Code text editors have operator pending concepts, but they don't have an additional operator-pending-like concept; it's clean that way: the expected results of key mappings are consistent and intuitive. You're answer is technically correct, it's just not intuitive or expected. It's a quirk that has to be learned.

Comment: I don't agree obviously. For me operating pending only makes sense for some operation that acts on whatever text you move over. So I wouldn't even expect operator pending mode to be active after a `CTRL-W` command.